# ES6 import equivalent of require() without exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, require, javascript-import

By using `require(./filename)` I can include and execute the code inside *filename* without any export defined inside *filename* itself.

What is the equivalent in ES6 using `import` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 132, accepted):

The equivalent is simply:

```
import "./filename";
```

Here are some of the possible syntax variations:

```
import defaultMember from "module-name";  

import * as name from "module-name";  

import { member } from "module-name";  

import { member as alias } from "module-name";  

import { member1 , member2 } from "module-name";  

import { member1 , member2 as alias2 , [...] } from "module-name";  

import defaultMember, { member [ , [...] ] } from "module-name";  

import defaultMember, * as name from "module-name";  

import "module-name";
```

**SOURCE:** [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: This actually appears to be incorrect according to the [same page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_a_module_for_its_side_effects_only) that you referenced in your answer.  That kind of import will execute code but not keep any references to variables that are defined (I confirmed this behavior in my project as well).

Comment: @brandaemon can you show an example of what you mean by “keeping variables”? How are you comparing the two? Native modules vs NodeJS or transpiling with Babel?

Comment: For example, if I have a file called `code.js` where I have `const foo = 1; console.log(foo);` and I say `import "code.js"` in `main.js`, I will not have access to `foo` inside `main.js`.  However, `1` will be printed to the console since the code inside `code.js` will execute.  If that's a little hard to follow, here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-lanbce?file=index.js) demonstrating what I'm doing.

Comment: @brandaemon That’s exactly how NodeJS & require works. It’s not that it’s not keeping references but those variables are *block scoped* so you cannot access them in  the calling module. If you had of put foo on either the window (browser) or global (Node) this would behave as you expect

Comment: Ah okay.  So there is no way to include scoped references without explicit `export`s?  I'm thinking of the behavior you get when you have multiple script tags in an HTML file.

Comment: @brandaemon There isn’t, no. I can see how you would think it would work the same way though!

Comment: It is likely that if you are having this problem you will also have to change the way you export from modules.  module.exorts = SomeObj  to export default SomeObj

Comment: Thank you for reminding very much, dear Everyone here! The following worked with Vite and some deprecated library: `import '@vendor/colorpicker/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min';` ( https://github.com/itsjavi/bootstrap-colorpicker ), where previously it was just a `<script>` in `<head>`. The outdated library partially works but jQuery..., and today... well... I hope they will consider finding a library alternative...

Comment: @CodingIntrigue What is the equivalent for: `var debug = require('debug')('my express app');`

Answer (score 1):

The answer should be changed, this does not work anymore as is. If you still want to use `import './otherfile.js'` without using exports, just to split your code up for readability you have to add `type="module` to the import of your js file in the html

`<script src="js/main.js" type="module"></script>`

Edit: It seems you also have to add the .js (otherfile.js) or it doesn't work anymore either.