# Add an external script to React and create new instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement this [github project](https://github.com/adolfintel/warpspeed) to my React web app. It is an external script to put a fancy canvas in the background.

I have tried to load it:

```
import {WarpSpeed} from './warpspeed.js'
import WarpSpeed from './warpspeed.js'
```

And then create a new instance:

```
let x = new WarpSpeed("canvasID")
```

But it throws an error:

> TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__helpers_warpspeed___default.a is not a constructor

I also tried to use [react-load-script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-load-script), but it does not make sense I cannot call new WarpSpeed after, because it is undefined.

Comment: Have you tried importing without { } - `import WarpSpeed from '...'`

Comment: @azrahel Yes I have tried, sorry I forgot to say. I got the same error message.

Comment: try importing whole file, without specifying explicit object and than `new WarpSpeed`. 
So `import "./warpspeed.js"`
hm, actually this might not work as stated here:

Import an entire module for side effects only, without importing anything. This runs the module's global code, but doesn't actually import any values.

`import '/modules/my-module.js';`

Comment: @azrahel "'WarpSpeed' is not defined  no-undef" :/
Yes I see your point. Hmm I guess I will have to create my own component and adapt the whole script for react.

Comment: if my answer helps you, please mark it as such :) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module you are trying to use will not work with commonjs importing. You will need to wrap the whole thing inside of a universal module definition.

Please use the one here:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tameemsafi/0d909a4060640b948f37ec59460f20d4/raw/c7f4e9020ccb1fb0a9dcf54221c67249030640eb/warpspeed-umd.js

I have wrapped it in a UMD IFFE which will allow you to use ES6 import. I also changed the `window.requestAnimationFrame` polyfill  to a better version.

You can place the code inside of a file `warpspeed.js`.

CommonJS:

`const WarpSpeed = require('./warpspeed.js');`

ES6 (Requires transpiling to commonjs):

`import WarpSpeed from './warpspeed.js'`

Comment: Wow thanks that is great! However I get these errors:
  Line 3:   'define' is not defined   no-undef
  Line 5:   'define' is not defined   no-undef
  Line 15:  Unexpected use of 'self'  no-restricted-globals
  Line 15:  Unexpected use of 'self'  no-restricted-globals

Comment: Did you copy and paste the whole thing into a new file from the gist? I updated the link to the raw version.

Comment: I updated it a-little now, and tested it with import using common js. It is working fine for me `const Warpspeed = require('./warpspeed.js')`. Are you using babel to transpile your es6 import?

Comment: Still the same. Yes, I guess I am using Babel, I used create-react-app to create my app.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work, I removed: if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define([], factory);
    } else
And changed self with window.self.
Thanks a lot ! :)

Answer (score 1):

According to this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_a_module_for_its_side_effects_only

other info I've found and after checking source code of WarpSpeed.js, what you want seems impossible.

You can also confirm it here:

[ES6 import equivalent of require() without exports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179828/es6-import-equivalent-of-require-without-exports)

You should probably add proper export to WarpSpeed.js file. 
Maybe fork the project, modify it so it is ES5+ compatibile and create pull request. Probably lib creator will be greateful ;)