# Vue - how can i load CSS and JS files in a component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm very new to Vue and i created a navbar component that i want to load.

Here is my code:

component.vue

```
<template>
    <html>
        <head>
        ...
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gudea:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Theme Styles -->
        <link href="assets/css/flatifytheme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
        ...
        </head>
        <body>
         ...
        
         <script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
         <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
         <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
         <script src="assets/plugins/waves/waves.min.js"></script>
         <script src="assets/plugins/uniform/js/jquery.uniform.standalone.js"></script>
         <script src="assets/plugins/switchery/switchery.min.js"></script>
         <script src="assets/plugins/pace/pace.min.js"></script>
         <script src="assets/js/flatifytheme.min.js"></script>

        </body>
    </html>
</template>
```

The `assets` directory is in the same folder as the component.

Now the problem is that i have a lot of `<link href=''>` and `<scripts>` tags that load js and css files of the theme i'm using for the navbar and i don't know where to put them in the component, so i keep getting the following error:

```
This relative module was not found:
* ./components/testComponent in ./src/main.js, ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
```

What does this error mean? How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @import in the style tag to import CSS-files.

@import './assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'

Also the paths to the files are incorrect, use `./`.

`./assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-3.1.0.min.js`

Comment: Thank you! So basically below </template>, i should add a <style></style> with inside the import you mentioned? Do i have to do this for both the link href and script tags?

Comment: No worries! Yes, Javascript-files are included like this it seems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55530604/how-to-include-local-script-files-in-vue :)

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of doing this:

1. Either these are global files in your project

   - load the remote files (google fonts any http files) directly in your index.html
   - load the project files via the bundler in your `main.js` or `App.vue`
   - with `import '@/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'` and so on...
2. Or, these are local files that need to be loaded in specific components

   - load the remote files (google fonts or any http files) with vue-meta plugin which helps your create links, script and other HTML tags on-the-fly in the **head** tag https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/api/#link
   - load the project files with `import '@/path/to/js/file'` for JS files or for CSS:

```
<style>
@import '@/path/to/js/file';
</style>
```

Comment: This is very clear! thank you a lot for answering!