# Import classic Javascript file

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a dependent classic JavaScript file which I cannot edit and I need to import. It looks like this:

```js
function DependencyInterface()
{
}

DependencyInterface.Foo = 'bar';

DependencyInterface.prototype.one = 1;
DependencyInterface.prototype.two = 1;

DependencyInterface.prototype.doSomething = function(dependencyPayload) {
  // ...
}

function DependencyPayload(value) {
  this.value = value;
}
```

I would like to use it, like this:

```js
import '@/scripts/DependencyInterface.js'
let dependencyInterface = new DependencyInterface();
dependencyInterface.doSomething(new DependencyPayload(3));
```

Unfortunately I am getting errors like:

- 'DependencyInterface' is not defined (no-undef)
- 'DependencyPayload' is not defined (no-undef)

I read from this post ([ES6 import equivalent of require() without exports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179828/es6-import-equivalent-of-require-without-exports)) that import statements like this are block scoped, and the only thing through are what is exported.

The only way around this I have found is to the dependency file in a public static location and do this in my root HTML:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= BASE_URL %>js/DependencyInterface.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.createDependencyInterface = function() { return new DependencyInterface() };
  window.createDependencyPayload = function(value) { return new DependencyPayload(value); }
</script>
```

But I really hate this solution. It isn't clean or scalable.

Is there any way to import this classic JavaScript file? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid not. Your solution is the only wait to do so. You can make it "cleaner" by using a function that dynamically updates the DOM to insert that `script` tag and executes a callback containing the rest of your code once the external dependency has correctly been loaded. Something like:

```
function loadScript(script, callback) {
  const dom = document.createElement('script');
  if (callback) dom.onload = callback;
  dom.type = (script.type) ? script.type : 'text/javascript';
  if (typeof (script) === 'object') {
    if (script.src) dom.src = script.src;
    if (script.integrity) dom.integrity = script.integrity;
    if (script.crossorigin) dom.crossOrigin = script.crossorigin;
  } else if (typeof (script) === 'string') {
    dom.src = script;
  }
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(dom, document.currentScript);
}

loadScript({ src: '<%= BASE_URL %>js/DependencyInterface.js' }, function () {
   // Your code here...
});
```